# How do I change permissions on an existing folder share from the command line without having to delete the share and recreate it?

Tags: windows-server-2008, command-line-interface, network-share

I used the following to create a folder share called "Running Virtual Machines" on a Hyper V R2 server:

```
net share "Running Virtual Machines"="C:\Hyper V\Running Virtual Machines"
```

Now I need to change the permissions on the share to allow users to access the share but using the following gives me the error "You used an option with an invalid value":

```
net share "Running Virtual Machines" /GRANT:domain/username,FULL
```

I have also tried:

```
net share "Running Virtual Machines"="C:\Hyper V\Running Virtual Machines" /GRANT:domain\username,FULL
```

This gives me the message "The name has already been shared."

How do I change permissions on an existing folder share from the command line without having to delete the share and recreate it?

Comment: Is 3rd party software an option? If so maybe this helps you: http://helgeklein.com/setacl/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the PowerShell cmdlets `Grant-SmbShareAccess` and `Revoke-SmbShareAccess`

There are some examples in this TechNet blog post: http://blogs.technet.com/b/omers/archive/2013/09/14/assigning-file-share-permissions-using-power-shell.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to make use of the [RMTSHARE](http://ss64.com/nt/rmtshare.html) utility, but it's an old program so you'll want to test thoroughly for your Windows Server 2008 environment.  You might have to disable UAC for it to work properly.